# '(props: any, context?: any): Component<any, any, any>' is deprecated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

One of the vs code extension is giving me this error

```
'(props: any, context?: any): Component<any, any, any>' is deprecated
```

and

```
@see — https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html
```

This is happening here

```
export default class MobileSheetColumn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      active: !!_.find(props.row.mobile_app_pages, { page_type: props.type })
    };
  }

  handleOnSwitchChange(type) {
    const { projects, updateProject, row } = this.props;
   // more code
```

I am unable to figure out the reason fo the same but if someone could help me than that would be super helpful

[image]

Ps: I am not using `contextTypes` from the legacy context docs

Comment: The [link they provided](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html) seems to explain it fairly well. What specifically don't you understand, having read that page?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think what's confusing is that the error is being thrown on `super(props)`, and it's not clear to me, reading that page, how `super(props)` relates to the legacy context api. (In my case, and perhaps @anny123 's, this is a codebase I didn't create, so I don't fully understand the role that `super(props)` played in the legacy context api, if any).